# WordPress Single-Product page hooks - How to insert a full width section without adding a description?

Tags: templates, woocommerce

I'm trying to build a single-product page like so:

1st row 50%/50% width:
Gallery / Title + Descripton + ACF fields

2nd row 100% width:
Custom Content based on Tags

3rd row 100% width:
Related Products

If I write anything as a product description, then the tabs section appears, and I am able to use filters like 'the_content' and hooks of all sorts like those that are available here: `https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/#tab-description`

However, if I don't add any description (which would be ideal), and the tabs section does not appear, than I am left with a situation like this: https://imgur.com/a/zUQOL19

I achieved this with:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_content_before_related_products', 19);
```

The 'custom content' starts on the right, and then falls on the next line to the left.

My question is, what method would you suggest, so that 'Custom Content' starts in a full-width container that I can customize?

I tried using different hooks, but so far all I tried either do this, or get inserted after the content (after related products to be exact), or before (before the gallery)

Is there a way to achieve this only with hooks, or do I need to build a single-product template using 'global $product' (even if not, I would be curious to learn what is wrong with this approach, and why is it commonplace to use hooks instead)?